# clean build byproduct files to store a backup

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

After running 'ionic build android' I usually keep a copy of the whole project directoy on Dropbox by previously compressing it. Nevertheless, as the project evolves it gets bigger and bigger, reaching now 100 MB. As I am out for vacation and running on a 4G network, I prefer to save my GBs... Is there a command to clean all these byproduct files I don't need?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use git to save and version your files.

It's a basic practise in programming and with it you can say which files/folders to ignore.

To answer to your question :

The files that you need to remove are the binaries (the files that are generated) and dependencies. You can retrieve them by lauching another build.
This are the following folders :

```
node_modules/
platforms/
plugins/
```

Don't forget to do an `ionic state save` before removing the plugins.
After you will need to do `ionic state restore` to restore yours platforms/plugins.